# XPATH - grab URL within div if certain class is found

Tags: xpath

```
<a class="card item" href="symatic-darcy-d/cadence-with-rhythm-%26-flow-%5B7%22%5D/CNP003-7inch" title="Symatic / Darcy D - Cadence With Rhythm &amp; Flow [7&quot;]">
<img class="lazy" src="thumb.png?CNP003-7inch" data-original="thumb.png?CNP003-7inch" alt="CNP003-7inch.png" style="display: block;">
<noscript><img src="thumb.png?CNP003-7inch" alt="CNP003-7inch.png" /></noscript>
<span class="artist">Symatic / Darcy D</span>
<span class="title">Cadence With Rhythm &amp; Flow [7"]</span>
<span class="description">"Combinations with Rhythm and Flow" is our first 7" skipless scratch tool created with portable scratching in mind.
 Featuring skip proof loops from "Combinations from the Masters" and "Cadence with Rhythm and Flow" portable scratchers have two scratch records in one re-configured to a pitch that works perfectly with portable set-ups.
 Side A - 83.33 BPM @ 33 1/3 RPM - Cadence with Rhythm and Flow
 Side B - 83.33 BPM @ 33 1/3 RPM - Combinations from the Masters
 Each side has 10 tracks of samples and a full sentence + bass tone and drums.</span>
<span class="ilabel">Cut &amp; Paste</span>
<span class="formats">7"</span>
</a>
```

I am trying to get these URLs but only if the format is `7"`

So in this case I want to return:

```
symatic-darcy-d/cadence-with-rhythm-%26-flow-%5B7%22%5D/CNP003-7inch
```

I can get the 7" bit but then can't grab the href.

```
//span[@class='formats'][contains(., '7"')]/parent::a/following-sibling::href/
```

Comment: which language are you binding?

Answer (score 0):

Please try xpath as

```
//span[@class='formats'][contains(., '7"')]//ancestor::a
```

Then try to get the href by using `get_attribute` equivalent for the language you are using for automation.